# Is it possible to programmatically access the .appx or executable of a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I know I can get to the readonly `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`, but is there any way to access the overall app container or executable?

My goal is to hash the entire package or executable in order to prevent tampering.

Comment: There's just no point to this, it is already being done.  A store app cannot start until the certificate is validated, that includes checking the file hashes.

Comment: @HansPassant What if the device is rooted and/or a user installs his own certificates? I'd feel more comfortable performing my own check as well.

Comment: Obviously this isn't nearly as brittle as you assume.  It would be *much* easier to disable your check, obscurity is not security.

Comment: @HansPassant Except that disabling my check would require reverse engineering my specific obfuscated app. I'm well aware this can be done, but it takes time and effort spent specifically on my app. Breaking the built in store app tampering detection is time and effort that can be put towards breaking any app on the platform.

Anyway, regardless of whether or not my planned efforts are worth the time or not, it remains a valid question. Is it possible?